# entirely edit drupal ecommerce theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I am having a big trouble finding a way to edit and change the content of the Omega Kickstart 7.x-3.4 (default theme) for eCommerce sites.

Firstly i made a sub theme of Omega Kickstart 7.x-3.4 (default theme) by using this link https://drupal.org/node/2057387 but I came to the point which i dont know how to make changes to the site and not speaking only regarding css but making my own new divs and content within.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this it would make my life easier.

Thanks a lot !!!!!!! Love Angelos

Answer (score 0):

The Commerce Kickstart Theme is based off the Omega Base Theme, so a healthy knowledge of Omega will allow you to manipulate the presentation of your website.

To edit the regions and zones of your site, you can edit the YOURTHEME.info file as per the tutorial or in the original [Omega Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1298694). The Zones and regions determine where you may place your blocks and content etc in the theme settings itself.

To configure the behaviour of the website, edit the regions (column width etc) on your sub-theme settings on your admin as such:

```
yoursite.com/admin/appearance/settings/THEME_NAME
```

Scott Tolinski of LevelUp Tuts did a tutorial on how to edit this which can be quite helpful:

```
http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorials/58-drupal-theming-omega-101-4-omega-settings
```

Finally, to tweak the CSS of your site, you will need to understand how the CSS is managed. All CSS should be located in your `\sites\YOUR_THEME\drupal-7.XX\sites\all\themes\THEME\css` folder.

By default Commerce Kickstart like all Omega themes will contain a `global.css`, `theme-alpha-default.css` `theme-alpha-narrow.css`, `theme-alpha-normal.css`, `theme-alpha-wide.css`files. Global is the primary CSS you'll be operating in, just be sure you tweak the CSS in a mobile first manner. Anner media query specfic styling should be handled in the appropriate style sheet.

Now, since you are using Kickstart there will be a *lot* of pre-configured CSS; some of which may become useless or unused if you tweak the regions and zones too much but hopefully once you understand Omega better you will be able to make tweaks to the aesthetic as appropriate. I highly recommend Level Up tuts video tutorials as a basic, and try to read the Omega Documentation to understand how to handle the theme appropriately.